Importar un archivo .SIF a un datagrid
Al importar la información de un archivo de texto me está multiplicando las filas con todas las columnas.
No puedo editar el archivo de texto debido a que así lo arroja un programa tercero.
El archivo muestra esto.

Al importarlo si me importa las Columnas  pero por cada columna me hace 1 registro ósea si son 6 columnas me registra 6 filas con la misma informacion.
string[] columnas = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:Mobiliario.sif");

string[] values;

for(int i = 0; i < columnas.Length; i++)
{
    values = columnas;

    string[] row = new string[values.Length];

    for(int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
    {
        row[j] = values[j].Trim();
    }

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Saludos

No se entiende, habas de columnas y filas como si supiéramos a lo que refieres. Lo que se ve en tu pregunta es un archivo con varias líneas, y en tu código se ve como lees las líneas con el evidente problema que estas duplicando el for, el primer for recorres "columnas" (que son líneas!!!! no columnas) y en el segundo recorres lo mismo ya que values = columnas;

Lo que tienes es un archivo de texto donde cada línea es un par clave/valor. La cuestión es si el archivo es un conjunto de registros o no. Puede ser que un conjunto de claves/valores constituya un registro. Pero en el archivo (incompleto) que muestras no se ve donde empieza y donde acaba el registro.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
